# How to make an image fold smoothly?

Tags: image

I want to put an image of stars (of the milky way to be precise) on my website. But the image is small and is repeated over the page. Therefore, I want the image to fold smoothly. This way if a visitor scrolls down the page he/she shouldn't be able to tell where the image ends - that is the tiling of the same image should be indiscernible.

Any ideas?

-sgsawant

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: @DMan 
My apologies... I do partially agree... Can you suggest a better stack where I could have posted this?

Comment: There's one in beta right now, and I found a thread on it that may be applicable to you: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2541/textures-how-to-use-in-web-design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the image in GIMP, then select Filters => Map => Make Seamless.